# Upload files to SSRS server

Tags: xslt, reporting-services, rss

I'm currently using the RS command to automate uploading an SSRS report.

I have created a VB.NET program and it works well.

Problem now is that I need to upload an XSLT file together with this report.  Anyone knows any way of doing this, either using VB or even directly to the SSRS SQL Server db?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to deploy these files directly from SSRS Report Project

Comment: Yes I did that previously and it worked fine.  Now I need to automate it.  What I'm looking for is essentially rs.CreateResource, but for XSLT rather than image files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - 
[Programatically upload XML file to SSRS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770210/programatically-upload-xml-file-to-ssrs-server)