# Programmatically upload XML file to SSRS server

Tags: xml, reporting-services

How do I programmatically upload an XSLT file to an SSRS server database?
I would like exactly the same functionality as the 'Upload File', preferably using the 'rs' command.

I have tried rs.CreateResource, but it doesn't seem to work for XML/XSLT files (though it works for Excel and image files)

I understand that manipulating the SSRS db is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.
The XSLT file was getting uploaded with a trailing null byte at the end of file.  Had to use a Hex viewer to see this.

To fix it I copied the array into another array, minus the last character and it's all good now.

```
Dim Temp() As Byte = New Byte(ArrayLength-1) {}
For i As Integer = 0 To ArrayLength-1
  Temp(i)=Contents(i)
Next
rs.CreateResource(XSLTFileName, ReportFolder, True, Temp, "application/xml", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code SSMS generated when I tried to upload an xml file:-
    Dim Resource As String = "home"
    Dim Parent As String = "/"
    Dim Overwrite As Boolean = false
    Dim Contents() As Byte = New Byte() {}
    Dim MimeType As String = "text/xml"
    Dim Properties(-1) As Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.[Property]

```
RS.CreateResource(Resource, Parent, Overwrite, Contents, MimeType, Properties)
```

Are you specifying the correct MimeType?

Comment: I'm trying your code above.

Could you please write the next couple of lines of your code?
The part where you put data into Contents -- did you use stream.Read(...)?

Comment: The code was scripted out of SSMS. But I think you would be able to do something like:-
   stream = File.OpenRead("<FILE NAME AND PATH>")
        fileData = New [Byte](stream.Length) {}
        stream.Read(fileData, 0, CInt(stream.Length))

Comment: Yup that's what I did.
My code:
Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(dir + filename)
Dim Contents() As Byte = New Byte(stream.Length) {}
stream.Read(Contents, 0, CInt(stream.Length))
stream.Close()
rs.CreateResource(XSLTFilename, ReportFolder, True, Contents, "application/xml", Nothing)